# ADO Pipeline - Restore Packages for DotNet 6

Tags: .net, azure-devops, msbuild, nuget

I have a dotnet solution containing test and library projects + an Azure Functions project.

I've updated all nuget packages to the latest versions and set the Azure Functions project to

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

In VS2022 everything now builds ok and all the tests pass.

However, when my Azure DevOps build pipeline runs its nuget restore task, I get lots of errors about various package incompatibility with net60 such as:

```
Package Serilog.Extensions.Hosting 4.1.2 is not compatible with net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0).
```

The yaml for the restore task of the build pipeline is:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
```

The build pipeline is set to run with:

```
jobs:
job: Build
displayName: Build
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'
```

Anyone explain why the solution would restore and build ok on my laptop but fail in pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default version of nuget embedded on the agent should not support your project.
I advise you to use the task "NuGet tool installer" with the version you use on your computer before doing your nuget restore.